# findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock within a for loop runs after loop ended, so I can't access array elements based on iteration counter

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I am using parse.com and Swift 2.

I need to find objects from parse within a for loop. The problem is, findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock is async, so when the closure within query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock runs, the loop was already finished and the index of iteration (i) has gone bigger then opIdList.count. So I get array index out of range error as opIdList, opUserIdlist and opLastIdChangedToList has same number of elements. Is there any easy solution that I am missing or do I have to use a sync function? (findObjects() in this case)

```
        for var i = 0; i < opIdList.count; ++i {
            let query = PFQuery(className: "LastId")
            query.whereKey("UserId", equalTo: opUserIdList[i])
            query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects, error) -> Void in
                if error == nil {
                    if objects?.count != 0 {
                        for object in objects! {
                            object.setValue(self.opLastIdChangedToList[i], forKey: "lastId")
                            object.saveInBackground()
                            processedOnes.append(i)
                        }
                    } else {
                        let item = PFObject(className: "LastId")
                        item["lastId"] = self.opLastIdChangedToList[i]
                        item["userId"] = self.opUserIdList[i]
                        item.saveInBackground()
                        processedOnes.append(i)
                    }
                }
            })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use recursion instead of a for loop. I didn't quite understand whats going on in your code but I implemented what the for loop does in a recursion below.

```
func reccursiveRquest(index:Int) {
    let query = PFQuery(className: "LastId")
    query.whereKey("UserId", equalTo: opUserIdList[index])
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects, error) -> Void in
        if error != nil {
            if objects?.count != 0 {
                for object in objects! {
                    object.setValue(self.opLastIdChangedToList[index], forKey: "lastId")
                    object.saveInBackground()
                    processedOnes.append(index)
                }
                if (index++) < opIdList.count { reccursiveRquest(index) }
            } else {
                let item = PFObject(className: "LastId")
                item["lastId"] = self.opLastIdChangedToList[index]
                item["userId"] = self.opUserIdList[index]
                item.saveInBackground()
                processedOnes.append(index)
                if (index++) < opIdList.count { reccursiveRquest(index) }
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As you say and as the name `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock` suggests, this runs in the background so it's asynchronous. You can't do what you're trying to do in this way.

Either you need to change your logic to allow the async tasks to complete and then finalise your processing or you need to run the query synchronously (and ensure that you aren't inappropriately blocking the current thread, especially if that thread is main).

It's possible that you can do the former by populating your array with `NSNull` and then replacing each item when it arrives. You will need some way to check that everything has finished so you can trigger that the array is ready to use.

In some ways it would be better to make it synchronous and run the whole thing on a background thread because that will also prevent you from making too many requests to the network at the same time. It's also then trivial to know when you're done and you can return the whole completed array.